# BIG CARTEL HELP - Text, Button and Link colours have changed on Big Cartel

Tags: css, bigcartel

I launched my Big Cartel shop two days ago after customising all the pages, layout, options etc.

I have just amended some of the information on some product pages (I did not touch the CSS) and when I refreshed the page to check the changes had been saved correctly, I noticed the colour of all my text, buttons, links and rollovers have changed!

I don't know why. In the CSS customisable section, the colours and fonts are all as they should be (they are all as I customised them to be - colour and font changes), but when I view my shop, they're different. I think they're back to the default settings/colours!?

Can anyone suggest why this might be? Please HELP!

Many thanks in advance,
Hannah

Comment: Hi Hannah, can you post a link to your store so I can take a look?